# Woocommerce View all Products in Pagination

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My client has asked me to add a 'View All' products button to the pagination section of their WordPress / Woocommerce site as well as having the page numbers http://www.nicholasjohninteriors.co.uk/product-category/lighting/.

I have found a couple of sites offering the code to do this but none seem to work if someone could provide me with some working code that would be great please?

Thanks,

James Isles

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free coding service. Read the page on [ask]

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure I understand what you mean and it says nothing about paying. How do I go about getting a question answered as I thought this was a forum for questions and answer?

Comment: This came up in a review queue of flagged questions. You said: `if someone could provide me with some working code that would be great please?`. That is asking for someone to give you, or write code. That is off-topic for this site. What you could do is add the code from one of those sites and explain how it is not working and / or the errors you are getting

Answer (score 1):

First of all add the code below to `functions.php` into your theme.

```
if( isset( $_GET['showall'] ) ){ 
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', create_function( '$cols', 'return -1;' ) ); 
}
else {
    add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', create_function( '$cols', 'return 12;' ) );
}
```

Then create a link in your theme view and pass the url like this:

```
<a href="https://www.nicholasjohninteriors.co.uk/product-category/lighting?showall=1">view all</a>
```

[Source](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/88370/show-all-products-on-one-page-with-woocommerce)

Comment: also remember it changes your default product_count to 12