# Woocommerce View all Products Link Pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, pagination

I'm trying to find a way to create view all button in the Woocommerce pagination.
All other sources seem to be outdated and not working.
Currently found one [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35015359/woocommerce-view-all-products-in-pagination) that is quite recent, but still not working.

So right now I have this:

```
if( isset( $_GET['showall'] ) ){ 
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', create_function( '$cols', 'return -1;' ) ); 
}
else {
    add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', create_function( '$cols', 'return 25;' ) );
}
```

And added this for the HTML link in the pagination.php:

```
    echo '<li><a href="';
    echo curPageURL();
    echo '?showall=1">All</a></li>';
```

The html link is showing, but it doesn't seem to run the function view all.

Is there something I may be doing incorrectly? or is this method outdated?

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `create_function` function may still be supported in some situations, but it is highly discouraged. It is actually one of a few functions that when enabled opens your website up to a number of hacking vulnerabilities, which is why in later versions of PHP it has been deprecated. I'd bet your host has it disabled and thus the code you have is not working possibly because of that.

Doing a quick google I found documentation on how to carry out what you said [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/change-number-of-products-displayed-per-page/). Now with a bit of modification based on what you have so far, I'd try this:

```
add_filter('loop_shop_per_page', 'my_per_page_filter', 100);

function my_per_page_filter($cols) {
  return isset($_GET['showall']) ? -1 : $cols;
}
```

In the code above I am using a bit of code magic to say if `$_GET['showall']` is set, then return -1 else the regular number of columns in `$cols`. I have also set the priority of the filter to 100 so hopefully it runs after other filters, if you find this code does not work then try a much higher value like 99999.

Hope this helps!

Koda

Comment: Hm, I've tested your code to no success. I believe I may have some problem calling the function. I'm trying the suffix of ?showall=1 and ?showall=-1 doesn't seem to work. Here's a link to the website if you would like to [test](http://kuzcolighting.com/beta/product-category/interior-lighting/chandeliers/). At the bottom of the page you can find the pagination and the View all Link. Sorry I am very new to php usually I am just touching the CSS/HTML of wordpress.

Comment: It looks like you are using a premium theme, which means no-one here can dive into the code without paying for it too. From what I can see the theme Flatsome uses an ajax loader for the products, which means normal woocommerce hooks will not work, you will need to contact the theme author for advice.

Comment: It's working now! I was adding all the code inside pagination.php previously. I tried testing it within function.php and its working now for some weird reason. Maybe inside pagination.php it couldn't detect loop_shop_per_page? Thanks Koda! Couldn't have done it without your help

Comment: Glad to have helped :)